How to get a preview on mouse hover?
I use the plugin nvim-ufo.  Everything works correctly, except that to get a preview a use a keymap.  I would like also to get the preview on mouse hover an unfolded block.  For now it give me the LSP documentation where my cursor is under the word.  The foldmethod is "indent".
Thk.

I find a way to mimic the mouse event to show the folded code.
I write an autocmd this way :
local function on_mouse_hover()

 local winid = require("ufo").peekFoldedLinesUnderCursor()
   if not winid then
      vim.lsp.buf.hover()
   end
end

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("cursorHold", {
   pattern = "*",
   callback = on_mouse_hover,
   desc = "Action sur hover du curseur - vois le code replié",
})enter code here

When you click the mouse on a folded block it will show you the preview. For that to work you need first to setup the plugin nvim-ufo.
If you dont click the mouse then it will show you the LSP documentation for the word under the mouse pointer.  I use the plugin "eagle-nvim" for that.
